# Dynamically sending input and select fields in php form

Tags: php, forms, post

I have a stock video request form where people can request certain lengths of stock video.  I have the one visible form sending fine beacuse I can $_POST its 'name' but people are able to "add more" if they want a number of clips.

I'm not sure how I would go about adding these dynamically created select and input fields into my PHP $_POST...  Add them to an array and foreach them out?  Or just add them all to an object and $_POST that object..?

Any help greatly appreciated!

HTML (note the inputGroupSelect02 is section that is getting dynamically added each time 'add more' is clicked.

```
<?php include("phpIncludes/header_nav.php") ?>


<section id="cinecoptersShowreel">



<!--CONTACT-->

<div id="contact" class="container contact-form">

<div id="contactAnchor"></div><!--CONTACT ANCHOR TAG-->


<form id="stockRequestWrapper" method="post" action="stockForm.php">
    <h3>Stock Footage Request</h3>
  <div class="row">
    
    <div class="col">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input id="nameInput" type="text" onchange="filledIn(this)" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name *" value="" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input id="emailInput" type="text" onchange="filledIn(this)" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email *" value="" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input id="companyInput" type="text" name="company" class="form-control" placeholder="Company" value="" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="formAdd" class="col">
      <div class="form-group">
        <select id="inputGroupSelect" name="stock" onchange="filledIn(this)" class="custom-select"  >
          <option id="chooseOption" selected>Stock Section...*</option>
          <option>Belfast</option>
          <option>Derry</option>
          <option>Dublin</option>
          <option>Water</option>
          <option>Countryside</option>
          <option>Misc</option>
        </select>

        <!-- <span class="text-primary">Please input   <strong>hours : mins : secs</strong>   only.  Frames are not required</span> -->
        <div class="input-group after-add-more"> 
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text">mm:ss</span>
          </div>
          <input id="tcIn" name="tcIn" type="time" onchange="filledIn(this)" step="any" class="form-control" >
          <span> to </span>
          <input id="tcOut" name="tcOut" type="time" onchange="filledIn(this)" step="any" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <input id="addMore"  type="button" value="Add more" class="btn add" />

      <div class="form-group">
        <input id="btnStockSubmit" disabled type="submit" name="btnStockSubmit" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit Stock Request" />
      </div>

</form>



<!-- HIDDEN  bits that are being copied when addmore is clicked if we copy the above form it will copy all items - so if theres 4 items there will be 8 rather than just adding one each time -->
<div class="copy hide">
  <div class="control-group input-group test">
    <hr>
        <select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect02" name="stock2">
          <option value="" selected disabled>Stock Section</option>
          <option value="1">Belfast</option>
          <option value="2">Derry</option>
          <option value="3">Dublin</option>
          <option value="4">Water</option>
          <option value="5">Countryside</option>
          <option value="6">Misc</option>
        </select>

      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text" name="addmore[]">mm:ss</span>
      </div>
    <input  type="time" step="any" class="form-control">
    <span> to </span>
    <input type="time" step="any" class="form-control">
    <div class="input-group-btn"> 
      <button class="btn btn-danger remove" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> -</button>
  </div>
  </div>

</div>



      </div>
    </div>
</div>




    </div>

  </div>
</form>
</div>

<!--/CONTACT-->






</section>


<?php include("phpIncludes/footer.php") ?>
```

jQuery

```
//UNDISABLES THE SEND MESSAGE BUTTON IN CONTACT US WHEN INPUTS ARE FILLED IN
function manage() {
  var bt = document.getElementById('contactSendBtnBtn');
  if (nameInput.value != '' && messageInput.value != '' && emailInput.value != '') 
  {
      bt.disabled = false;
  }
  else {
      bt.disabled = true;
  }
}

//UNDISABLES THE SEND MESSAGE BUTTON IN STOCK US WHEN INPUTS ARE FILLED IN (this is same as above only with jquery instead of vanilla JS)

function filledIn() {
  let btn = $("#btnStockSubmit");
  let request = $('select').on('change', function() {
    ( $(this).find(":selected").val() );
  });
 

  if($("#nameInput").val() != '' && $("#emailInput").val() != '' && 
  $(request).val() !== "Stock Section...*" && $("#tcIn").val() != '' && $("#tcOut").val() != '') {

    btn.attr("disabled", false);
  }
  else {
    btn.attr("disabled", true);
  };
  
};


//MOVING THE SELECTED CLASS TO THE CORRECT OPTION
$(document).on("change","select",function(){
  $("option[value=" + this.value + "]", this)
  .attr("selected", true).siblings()
  .removeAttr("selected")
});
```

PHP POST FORM

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['btnStockSubmit'])) {

    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
    $email_to = "EMAIL@EMAIL.COM";
    $subject = "Stock Submission Form";



    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');      
    }

    $full_name = $_POST['name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $company = $_POST['company'];
    $stock = $_POST['stock'];
    $tcIn = $_POST['tcIn'];
    $tcOut = $_POST['tcOut'];



    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The e-mail you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$full_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($full_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Company: ".clean_string($company)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Stock Reel: ".clean_string($stock)."\n";
    $email_message .= "TC In: ".($tcIn)."\n";
    $email_message .= "TC Out: ".($tcOut)."\n";
    $email_from = $full_name.'<'.$email_from.'>';


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $subject, $email_message, $headers);



?>

<!-- include your own success html here -->
<?php include ("phpIncludes/header_nav.php") ?>

<h1>Thanks for your message. We'll get back to you ASAP!</h1>

<?php include ("phpIncludes/footer.php") ?>



<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: I don’t get what your actual question is here. It does not look like you are using AJAX, but are just submitting your form normally … so the values of all fields will be provided in $_POST already (if you named them appropriately), that is nothing you have to specifically facilitate using any extra steps.

Comment: Question is how to add the dynamically created items to the POST.  Not using AJAX no.

Comment: If you have multiple form fields with the same name, then you need to use the `foo[]` syntax with the braces for the field names, otherwise PHP will overwrite those parameters, and you will only get the last one.